# PHP: Categorizing images into database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website in PHP to share my comics. I'd like to implement categorization to allow people to filter which comics they'd like to see.

I've asked this question before, but at that time my site's architecture was not using a database.I've since implemented a database (which is amazing, btw) so I need to change things up.

I'm thinking the way to do this is:

1) Make 2 tables: 1 for categories, 1 for images

2) Insert images into their respective tables based on which filesystem folder they're in and assign that table id

3) Insert all images into All_Images table with their newly assigned category id

4) Take in user input to decide which images to show. So, if user input = cat 1, then show images with category 1 id.

So, basically I need a way to initially assign categories to the images when they come in from the filesystem. **Is there an easier way to do this? Do I have to create multiple tables?**

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think a tagging design would be more adequate for something fuzzy as an image category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way would be to have an images table (presumably with filenames rather than the actual images?) and then a one-to-many relationship to categories so that each comic can have more than one:

```
Table:Image
-----------
rowid: integer identity
displayname: varchar
filename: varchar

Table:Category
--------------
rowid: integer identity
displayname: varchar

Table:ImageCategoryLink
-----------------------
imageid: integer foreign key references Image:rowid
categoryid: integer foreign key references Category:rowid
```

Clear?

Comment: So it appears I actually do need more than one table. This is what I was thinking. I'll give this a try, thank you!

Comment: As Fry_95 mentioned. If you definitely only ever want one category per comic then you could add a column to the image table but this way allows you some flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

One table category with id and name etc, one table for image with id src name etc.

Two choices after that :

- If an image has one and only one category, put a field id_category in table image
- If an image can has several categories make another table image_category with id_image and id_category

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beginner (no offence) and I don't think there will be millions or cartoons in the table. Use a SET field (or ENUM if your cartoon can only have one category) for you categories.

There are people who will vote this down since there are some negative side effects of using this (mainly when you want to change the categories). But with a relative small table this will not have any effect.

This will be the easiest solution. If you expect the site to grow big, use a second table for your categories and join the tables.